# Facebook iFrame tab page - share and comments - how?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe, facebook-page, iframe-app

I'm new to this. I've made a iframe tab page and added to my Facebook page from instructions on the internet. Now, on my tab page, I have 5 songs list to giveaway. Each song should have a 'download' and 'comments' link beside it.
1. For the 'download' link, after user clicked and the 'save as' box appeared, how do I post to user's wall something like "have downloaded the song Bla Bla Bla from ArtistXYZ fan page! Get it for yourself!"
2. How do I make the 'comment' part working?
Thank you.

Comment: How about explaining what do you mean by *comment part*?

Comment: Comment part - user should be able to make comments about the song, similar to comment system in Facebook, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to let the users authorize your application to access the songs list (with `publish_stream` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/))
2. On download [publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) the message to the user wall
3. For the comment part you need to use the [comment plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)
4. You need a similar approach just like in the [Linkin Park Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/linkinPark), and the approach is explained [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/).